# Issue with creating custom tag library using OSGI bundle

Tags: tags, maven-3, aem, osgi-bundle

I am trying to create custom tag libs by using OSGI bundles in cq. Actually i created all the necessary files but i could not place my mytags.tld file under META-INF folder in build time. For that i used `maven-bundle-plugin` plugin. Here is my code to include the resource in META-INF folder

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Include-Resource>META-INF/myTags.tld=target/classes/META-INF/myTags.tld</Include-Resource>
        </instructions>
        <Export-Package>com.mine.*</Export-Package>
        <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package> 
        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Note**: i have placed my tag file under "src\main\resources\META-INF\myTags"

I have used `<Include-Resource>` to include my tld file. But i could see my tld file under META-INF folder after jar file is created.

Here is my build error

> [ERROR] Bundle com.mine-bundle:bundle:1.0-SNAPSHOT : Input file does
>   not exist: target/classes/META-INF/myTags.tld

Could you anyone tell what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `<Include-Resource>` parameter is redundant. If you don't specify it, maven-bundle-plugin will include all resources from `src/main/resources` to the output JAR, as the [official doc](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#ApacheFelixMavenBundlePlugin%28BND%29-%7B%7B%3CIncludeResource%3E%7D%7D) says:

> By default the bundle plugin converts the project's Maven resource
>   directories into a single  instruction. If you
>   specify your own  instruction, this will replace the
>   generated one.

So if you have TLD file placed in `src/main/resources/META-INF`, it should be included without additional options.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in IntelliJ if there was no `src/main/resources` folder. Adding a dummy properties file to that location fixed it.